# Continuum Hypothesis for closed sets

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In A Beginner's Guide to Modern Set Theory [page 48], the author says:

> [Cantor] did prove that every closed uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$...

... but I cannot find the proof anywhere, and it doesn't seem trivial. Can someone help me, either by pointing me to a proof, or proving it directly?

Comment: The argument is as outlined in the answer. For details, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/740350/462).

Comment: More generally, any uncountable Borelian subset of a Polish space has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$. See here: https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/the-continuum-hypothesis-for-borelian-sets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *perfect* set is a set which is equal to the set of its limit points. (In particular, it's closed.)

Any nonempty perfect subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

The *Cantor Bendixson Theorem* states that any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written (uniquely) as the disjoint union of a countable set and a perfect set. Hence an uncountable closed set contains a nonempty perfect set, and hence has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

(The above two statements about $\mathbb{R}$ work for [Polish spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) more generally.)

Comment: The definition of [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) excludes isolated points.