# Uncountable sets of real numbers that do not contain uncountable closed subsets

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Prove there are uncountable sets of real numbers that do not contain uncountable closed subsets. (Hint: one can show the existence of a set X in R that does not contain any subset Y having the properties that Y is closed and contains no isolated points.)

This is a question from the book Integration and Modern Analysis. I guess for the hint, one can assume every set in R contains some subset Y that is closed and contains no isolated points, and contradict it with a counterexample such as {1,2}. How can one go from here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You'll need the set you build to be **uncountable**, too, so $\{1,2\}$ isn't relevant. It turns out that there's no easy way to prove this - the existence of an uncountable set of reals with no uncountable closed subset cannot be proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= usual mathematics *without* the axiom of choice). You'll need to use transfinite recursion here (with choice being used to set the recursion up in the first place).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct a Bernstein set and what are their applications?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set)

Answer (score 1):

The proof of this requires the Axiom of Choice. In particular, without the Axiom of Choice it is consistent that every set of real numbers has the [perfect set property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property), which is equivalent to the negation of your exercise.

---

To construct an uncountable set of real numbers that does not contain an uncountable closed subset, enumerate the set of all uncountable closed subsets (there are $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ many such sets) as a transfinite sequence $\langle C_\alpha\mid\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}\rangle$. Then, recursively go through these sets and pick two points $r_\alpha,s_\alpha\in C_\alpha$ that are different from every $r_\beta,s_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$. This is always possible, since at stage $\alpha$ of the recursion, you picked less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ many points, and $|C_\alpha|=2^{\aleph_0}$ (and in case the latter is not clear, see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/740350/176025)).

Finally, let $R=\{ r_\alpha\mid \alpha<2^{\aleph_0}\}$ and $S=\{ s_\alpha\mid \alpha<2^{\aleph_0}\}$, then either of these two sets satisfies the property that they are uncountable and do not contain any uncountable closed subset.

Sets like this $R$ are called [Bernstein sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set), by the way.

Comment: We also need the result that any closed uncountable subset $C_{\alpha}$ of reals has cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ so that  $C_{\alpha}\setminus \cup_{\beta<\alpha}\{r_{\beta},s_{\beta}\}$ so that $r_{\alpha}$ and $s_{\alpha}$ can exist.

Comment: Indeed, I believe I mentioned this as $|C_\alpha|=2^{\aleph_0}$, at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: Yes but I do not think $|C_{\alpha}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ is obvious and a student reading an intro to analysis would likely not know it nor how to prove it. It's not a flaw in your answer though.

Comment: Agreed again. If this isn't clear, then likely there was no prior treatment of uncountable perfect sets being of size continuum either, or of the Cantor-Bendixson theorem, in which case I personally think this a bit of a sadistic exercise...

Comment: This question has a good exposition of the size of uncountable closed sets: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/740350/176025

Comment: A problem (verbatim) from American Monthly Monthly: "A student asserted that any uncountable set of reals contains a closed uncountable subset. Is this true?" My first thought was it was very likely true that a student had asserted this.

Comment: I  like your most recent comments....Any non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set and any uncountable closed set in $\Bbb R$ has an uncountable closed subset with no isolated points.